# Firefox not displaying pdf files correctly with in browser pdf viewer

Tags: firefox, pdf, acrobat, adobe-reader

So Strange issue here, if you go to this PDF file in firefox http://skincarerx.com/p_include/rebates/sc13-9842-003-skincarerx-dec-rebate-offer.pdf

you will notice on the right that a bunch of text is missing. There are more steps and the terms and conditions are missing on the bottom.

If you open the same link in Adobe Reader or Chrome (again using Adobe Reader) All the text shows up correctly.

I have tried saving the PDF as an older version of Acrobat but it didn't seem to have any effect on it.

I have seem pages Referring to FF internal PDF reader as the problem but no fix (besides not having it open in ff internal reader). I need a solution that will still allow the PDF to display correctly for the user in FF without having to disable the internal reader.

Original File was saved in Adobe Acrobat Pro

Comment: It seems that you may have uncovered a bug in PDF.js, which is the HTML5 PDF reader used by default with Firefox. The project page is [here](https://mozillalabs.com/en-US/pdfjs/), from where you can find links to Github and the bug reporting mechanism. Short of disabling PDF.js or reformatting your document, you'll be waiting for a bugfix.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about bugs in a 3rd-party product.

Comment: File opens OK in PDF.js on Linux or WinXP, but text is missing on Windows 8.1. If I unembedd fonts, it opens OK on Windows 8.1 too. If I embedd them again on Windows 8.1 using Adobe software (Acrobat or InDesign) -- text missing in Firefox, again. If I embedd manually using latest (Win 8.1) Arial -- text missing, if using old Arial from XP -- text OK, opening in Firefox in 8.1. If I type with Arial in Notepad in 8.1 and print to AdobePDF and open in Firefox - text missing. Weird bug, it's strange if no one found it yet. My advice is unembedd fonts and embedd older Arial version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same Firefox problem. I replaced Arial regular with MS Arial Unicode and the issue went away.
Funny that short documents with 2-4 pages were not effected only one document 24 pages long had the problem. Now the 24 pager works in all browsers.